# How to Run From .txt File?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get data from base58 combination by appending to the end of strings.

```
#!c:\perl64\bin\perl.exe
 
{$db = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$pw="Rw5cfDTA8zGsdjEhKnhXJTH7LrciGrDi9qZ1";
@delen = split('',$pw);
@letters = split('',$db);
$length = length($pw);
for ($position = 36; $position < $length+1; $position++)
{foreach(@letters)
    {
        @new = @delen;
        splice(@new, $position, 0, $_);
        print join('',@new)."\n";
    }}}
```

I have to enter all the combinations one by one in the $ pw definition. Instead of entering it manually, I want it to process all lines of my list in the TXT file. I did some research on how to do it but failed.

**EDITING:**

I found the method I mentioned above, it will be exactly like this. However, I have a different problem. When I run the Perl file, the outputs are sequenced badly. I think there's a problem getting from the input file

```
#!c:\perl64\bin\perl.exe

open( my $data, "<", "test.txt" ) or die "There was a problem opening: $!";

while ($data) {
    {
        my $db = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        my $pw = <$data>;
        my @delen   = split( '', $pw );
        my @letters = split( '', $db );
        my $length  = length($pw);
        for ( my $position = 35 ; $position < $length + 1 ; $position++ ) {
            foreach (@letters) {
                my @new = @delen;
                splice( @new, $position, 45, $_ );
                print join( '', @new ) . "\n";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get `There was a problem opening: ..` error when running the second script.

Comment: Please try and clarify your question. It's not totally clear what you want from its initial title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**# Final**

As a result of long efforts, I got the result I wanted. This works flawlessly for me.

```
#!c:\perl64\bin\perl.exe

open( my $data, "<", "4.txt" ) or die "There was a problem opening: $!";

while ($data) {
    {
        my $db = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        my $pw = <$data>;
        my @delen   = split( ' ', $pw );
        my @letters = split( '', $db );
        my $length  = length($pw);
        for ( my $position = 39 ; $position < $length + 1 ; $position++ ) {
            foreach (@letters) {
                my @new = @delen;
                splice( @new, $position, 0, $_ );
                print join('', @new ) . "\n";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**#FINAL 2**

It is now out of the loop.

The only mistake is: `splice() offset past end of array at`

```
#!c:\perl64\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $data, "<", "file_in.txt" ) or die "There was a problem opening: $!";

while (my $pw = <$data>) {
    my $db = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    my @delen   = split( ' ', $pw );
    my @letters = split( '', $db );
    my $length  = length($pw);
    for ( my $position = 38 ; #line break
    $position < $length + 1 ; $position++ ) {
        foreach (@letters) {
            my @new = @delen;
            splice( @new, $position, 0, $_ );
            print join('', @new ) . "\n";
        }
    }
}
close $data;
```

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to accept your own answer.

Comment: Your `while ($data)` seems strange. `$data` contains a filehandle, so it will always be true. I wonder if you meant `while (<$data>)` (which would also mean you probably need to change `$pw = <$data>` to `$pw = $_`).

Comment: I don't know the coding language, I just edited it through research. I am very newbie so I have no idea about your question. But as far as I understand it reads "$ data" from the file and passes it to $ pw.

Comment: That's a terrible way to learn a language. Perhaps spend some time reading [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/).

Comment: `$pw = <$data>` means "read a record from the filehandle `$data` and store it in `$pw`". But it's the `while ($data)` that is (probably) wrong. That means "do this while `$data` is true". But as `$data` is a filehandle, it will always be true and your loop will never end.

Comment: How many lines are there in your input file? If there are many and you want to process them all, then you need to loop using `while (<$data>)` (note the extra `<...>`). If there's only a single line, then you don't need the `while` loop at all.

Comment: Yes, there is this problem. But I didn't mind because I don't have enough information. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, and you should probably look at the [`chomp()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp) function as well.

Comment: With Final 2, it is now out of the loop. There is only one bug left to fix, but it works flawlessly like this :)